# Compare values of string SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Sqlite

Parameter A = '74'
Parameter B = '1'

I have a string concatenated like this '74~1~340' , this string is the value for a column 'vc_ValueAnswer', in the table 'Motor_Answers', so, I need compare the first value '74' with the first parameter incoming and the second value '1' with the second parameter incoming, if this two values is correct, then return the the third value '340', the string could be also like this '5~1~340', how can i separate the values for compare them? I'm using 'SQLite Maestro'

Comment: How about concatenating the columns and comoaring that?

Comment: Leon, how is your idea ?

Comment: Create a variable to constenate the parameters to patially match the string in the table. Then use Something like SELECT vc_ValueAnswer FROM Motor_Answers WHERE vc_ValueAnswer LIKE concatenatedParameters. Then in code strip the last value. It has a lot of overhead, but the code it simplistic

Comment: mmm, ok, nice idea, I'll try give me a moment...

Comment: ready, it's a simply solution, but works